# Как правильно организовать обратную связь в MVVM между ViewModel и View

Tags: c#, mvvm

Проблема в следующем:

`VM` не знает какое у неё `View` (это может быть и `WPF`, и `Xamarin` и прочие). Обработчик ошибок осуществляется по средствам интерфейса. Он един для всех представлений. Имеется так же действия которые совершаются в рамках одного представления, например, после успешной авторизации перейти на страницу или обновить `DataGrid`.

В настоящий момент проблема решается плохо. Создаётся в `VM` публичный  статический класс `Helper`, а во `View HelperSet` который заполняет `Helper` всеми недостающими действиями.

Как это делается правильно?

Этот метод используется во всех командах:

```
public static void FireAndForgetSafe(this Action action, IErrorHandler? handler)
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
        catch (ResultNotFoundException ex)
        {
            if (handler is IErrorNotFoundHandler handlerWithNotFound)
                handlerWithNotFound.HandleResultNotFound(ex);
            else handler?.ErrorHandle(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            handler?.ErrorHandle(ex);
        }
    }
```

`DataGrid` необходимо обновить, то есть вызвать `Refresh()`

Comment: Было бы проще разобрать пример на основе кода и разметки, а не слов.

Comment: Хотелось бы понять как это в общем делать

Comment: `FireAndForgetSafe` это `async void` такая обертка делается обычно, а у вас всё синхронное. Смысла в такой обертке для синхронного кода нет, так как всплытие исключений в синхронном коде работает нативно как обычно. Перемудрёж. :) "запустил-и-забыл" это не про синхронный код.